# IF Function Query - Extended

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, cells, ampersand

I got an answer for a previous question regarding an IF function on my excel tracking sheet.

I would like to further this by adding another formula to the existing formula.

> I am looking for some help regarding an IF function on an Excel
>   document.
>
> Basically if the Date Listed cell is dated over 1 month ago (eg: Date
>   Listed 6-Aug but today is 6-Sep) and the Date Sold cell is blank, then
>   I would like the Mark Down cell to say 'MARK DOWN', which at the
>   moment it does but it is only 10-Aug today.
>
> If the Date Listed cell and the Date Sold cell both contain dates I
>   would like the Mark Down cell to say 'OK'.
>
> So far I have this written:
>
> `=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(G2),MONTH(G2),DAY(G2)), ISBLANK(H2)),"MARK DOWN","OK")`
>
> I know I'm not far off but I need help sorting out the
>   last parts..
>
> Bonus if you can help me add a highlighted cell formatting to it :)!
>
> [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ouu1.jpg)

******Original formula:

`=IF(AND((TODAY()-G11)>31,ISBLANK(H11)),"Mark Down","No")`******

My additional query is:

If this item hadn't been uploaded yet, therefore there would be no date in the Date Listed cell, I would like to have an ISBLANK function which returns with "Not Required".

I have read something about ampersands and joining functions but not sure how to use them properly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
=IF(AND((TODAY()-G19)>31,ISBLANK(H19)),"Mark Down","No"), OR(ISBLANK(G19)),"Not Required")
```

Thanks again.

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(G19),"Not required",IF(AND((TODAY()-G19)>31,ISBLANK(H19)),"Mark Down","No"))` I wrote this in notepad in 20 seconds but you can try it.

Comment: Had to make one small change but otherwise this worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Would recommend putting this and the small change into an answer and then accepted so this question can be closed